# How can I fix this syntax error: unexpected INTEGER NUMBER?

Tags: memory, verilog

I try to build a 4-bit CPU which can implement ADD(000), AND(001), OR(010), NOT(011), SLT(100), SM(101), LM(110), and LI(111), and I get the following errors:

> Error: (vlog-13069) D:/modelsim/examples/cpu.v(48): near "=": syntax
>   error, unexpected '=', expecting ++ or --.
>
> Error: (vlog-13069) D:/modelsim/examples/cpu.v(53): near "3": syntax
>   error, unexpected INTEGER NUMBER.
>
> Error: (vlog-13069) D:/modelsim/examples/cpu.v(56): near "and": syntax
>   error, unexpected and.

How can I fix it?

The following is my Verilog code:

```
module cpu(instruction, register0, register1, register2, register3,
            memory0, memory1, memory2, memory3, memory4, memory5, memory6, memory7,
            memory8, memory9, memory10, memory11, memory12, memory13, memory14, memory15, overflow);
input [8:0] instruction;
output [3:0] register0; output [3:0] register1; output [3:0] register2; output [3:0] register3;
output [3:0] memory0; output [3:0] memory1; output [3:0] memory2; output [3:0] memory3;
output [3:0] memory4; output [3:0] memory5; output [3:0] memory6; output [3:0] memory7;
output [3:0] memory8; output [3:0] memory9; output [3:0] memory10; output [3:0] memory11;
output [3:0] memory12; output [3:0] memory13; output [3:0] memory14; output [3:0] memory15;
output overflow;
//there are 8 kinds of op code for u to choose.
//u can save four nums in register, or save 16 nums in memory. there's also a num for u to check it's overflow or not

reg overflow;
reg [3:0] register [3:0];
reg [3:0] memory [15:0];
reg [1:0] rs, rt, rd;
reg [2:0] op;
//create four 4-bits registers, and sixteen 4-bits memories.
//rs, rt, rd are the addresses of the register or memory

reg [3:0] c, a, b, address;
reg [4:0] sum;
//a, b used to calculate the num stored in register or memory
//address is the address of memory
//for checking out the overflowing, we need 'sum' to be 5-bits

integer i;
initial
begin
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
    register [i] = 4'b0000;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1)
    memory[i] = 4'b0000;
end
//initialize all the register and memory

//your code~
always@(*)begin
op = instruction[8:6];
rs = instruction[5:4];
rt = instruction[3:2];
rd = instruction[1:0];

case(op)
    3'b000:
    a = register[rs];
    b = register[rt];
    sum = a + b;
    overflow = sum[4];//if overflow is 1, then it does.
    register[rd] = sum;

    3'b001:
    a = register[rs];
    b = register[rt];
    and f0(c[0], a[0], b[0]);
    and f1(c[1], a[1], b[1]);
    and f2(c[2], a[2], b[2]);
    and f3(c[3], a[3], b[3]);
    register[rd] = c;

    3'b010:
    a = register[rs];
    b = register[rt];
    or f0(c[0], a[0], b[0]);
    or f1(c[1], a[1], b[1]);
    or f2(c[2], a[2], b[2]);
    or f3(c[3], a[3], b[3]);
    register[rd] = c;

    3'b011:
    a = register[rs];
    b = register[rt];
    not f0(c[0], a[0], b[0]);
    not f1(c[1], a[1], b[1]);
    not f2(c[2], a[2], b[2]);
    not f3(c[3], a[3], b[3]);
    register[rd] = c;

    3'b100:
    a = register[rs];
    b = register[rt];
    if(a < b) begin
    register[rd] = 4'b0001;end
    else begin
    register[rd] = 4'b0000;end

    3'b101:
    address = instruction[3:0];
    memory[address] = register[rs];//can i really write like this?

    3'b110:
    address = instruction[5:2];
    register[rd] = memory[address];//can i really write like this?

    3'b111:
    a = instruction[5:2];
    register[rd] = a;

endcase
end

assign register0 = register[0]; assign register1 = register[1];
assign register2 = register[2]; assign register3 = register[3];
assign memory0 = memory[0]; assign memory1 = memory[1];
assign memory2 = memory[2]; assign memory3 = memory[3];
assign memory4 = memory[4]; assign memory5 = memory[5];
assign memory6 = memory[6]; assign memory7 = memory[7];
assign memory8 = memory[8]; assign memory9 = memory[9];
assign memory10 = memory[10]; assign memory11 = memory[11];
assign memory12 = memory[12]; assign memory13 = memory[13];
assign memory14 = memory[14]; assign memory15 = memory[15];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple lines in a `case` statement branch must be enclosed between `begin` and `end`, eg

```
3'b000:
begin
  a = register[rs];
  b = register[rt];
  sum = a + b;
  overflow = sum[4];//if overflow is 1, then it does.
  register[rd] = sum;
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but there's still some problem here